# Saving information to mysql table

Tags: php, html

So I want to create an html form and save it to a databas in WordPress

First I created the form which I put on this page  [here](https://adsler.co.uk/dating/)

```
<form action="addperson.php" method="post">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"/><br>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"/><br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name=submit value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then, in public html-->wp-content-my theme I created a file called `addperson.php`
In this file I put the following code :

```
<?php
//Block 1
$user = "user"; //Enter the user name 
$password = "password"; //Enter the password
$host = "host"; //Enter the host
$dbase = "database"; //Enter the database
$table = "table"; //Enter the table name

//Block 2
$firstname= $_POST['firstname_entered'];
$lastname= $_POST['lastname_entered'];
$email= $_POST['email_entered'];

//Block 3
$connection= mysql_connect ($host, $user, $password);

if (!$connection){
    die ('Could not connect:' . 
    mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

//Block 4
$username_table= mysql_query( "SELECT username FROM $table WHERE username= '$username'" ) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error()); 

//Block 5
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2, value 3)");

//Block 6
echo 'You have been added.';

//Block 7
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Then I created a database and a table `email_list` like so:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    email_list (first_name VARCHAR(50), 
    last_name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR 
    (50));
```

Next, I entered info into form[here](https://adsler.co.uk/dating/)

It saved absolutely nothing.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your HTML.

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname"/>
<input type="text" name="lastname"/>
<input type="text" name="email"/>
```

And after submiting form, that data will be under *firstname, lastname, email* keys in `$_POST` array.

So you probably should change this

```php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname_entered'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname_entered'];
$email = $_POST['email_entered'];
```

to this

```php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

You should also consider enabling errors displaying in php to get more info about your potentials mistakes.

```php
// Put this on top of your php file
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Thanks. Did what you suggested but it still hasn't saved anything

Comment: I've been on your website and you probably forgot to register that form endpoint to your abstract router or something. I can't tell you more because i don't know how it works in your implementation

Comment: Dunno. Maybe, yeah.